# Tableau: Clustering based on value-range for map coloring

Tags: clustering, tableau

Is there a possibility to cluster coloring for certain statistical ranges?

This is what I have been able to achieve so far.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as an example, create a binned field for the measure. The value range can be specified in the tooltip. I used a single color based continuous palette since (population) total is a continuous field.

[Edited]
Based on your comment, I tested with a fixed dimension based binned field for the continuous measure. At least in my example file, the values make more sense now with the new binned field. I see China at 16M population, India at 14M and so on.

[image]

If this solution is relevant to your use case, you will need to be careful with dimensions included/excluded in the fixed calculation.

Comment: That's what I had initially. The thing is, I am ZN(SUM(..)), so NULLs are replaced with 0. Maybe N/A  shall be used for those countries. Anyway. I want to cluster the colors based on SUM ranges. If that is possible. Thanks for you response.

Comment: @Andewan09, can I send you my twbx och excel files?

Comment: Adewan09, we have different statistical data, I am not able to produce what you produced. However, if possible, I can send all of my files over to you and let you tweak with them and send them back to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JohnSmith, sure send your files over

Comment: Adewan09, where can I send the files?

Comment: so.john.smith.94@gmail.com